Which judo throws do require a gi to work properly?
In the context of no-gi Brazilian Jiujitsu, "classic" judo throws are often overlooked in favor of wrestling techniques, although there is certainly an overlap between the two. And it does represent an additional challenge that some/many judo throws require to get a grip on the opponents gi.
While throwing can be done in no-gi with variations on grips, e.g., cupping behind the elbow instead of grabbing the cloth, I was wondering which judo throws would absolutely require a gi or at least make the throw a lot easier to execute. I am thinking of techniques like tomoe nage, which seem impossible to me to pull off on a resisting opponent when pulling on shirts is not allowed and cupping under both armpits is also difficult to achieve.

Tomoe nage can be done by grabbing anything in order to unbalance. It ideally doesn't require much force to unbalance someone who's already unbalanced. For example, someone leaning over you while your back is on the ground, and you grab a hold of his wrist while planting your leg on his abdomen. He's over-extended when you apply it, so it takes little effort to unbalance. You can also create the unbalance by performing a different throw or a takedown first, and then turning it into tomoe-nage once he's unbalanced. Just throwing that out there. Haha!

Maybe this should be several questions each relating to one or two judo techniques... there are about 60 odd right?

As you say, some throws only use one sleeve grip which can be naturally substituted for an elbow grip (e.g. o-goshi, koshi-guruma, ippon-seoi-nage, ura-nage). Some throws don't use the gi at all, and are directly equivalent (e.g. morote-gari, kata-guruma).
Throws that mechanically require a jacket to grip (and can't naturally substitute hooks, a collar tie, or a wrist/elbow grip) to execute would seem to boil down to:

those allowing a person to grip the gi and turn (e.g. a front lapel or sleeve grip)
those pulling with a belt or back grip




Requires a belt grip
Requires a back grip
Requires a lapel grip
Requires a sleeve grip
Requires a sacrifice pull forwards




obi-otoshi
tsuri-goshi  sumi-otoshi
seoi-nage seoi-otoshi tsuri-komi-goshi   uki-otoshi  sumi-otoshi
sode-tsuri-komi-goshi
hikikomi-gaeshi



This isn't exhaustive and there will be debate over when a variation is too different to be still considered the 'same' technique (e.g. there is a variation of tai-otoshi which can be done with a wrist and inner elbow grip), but it should cover most non-sacrifice techniques.
Note that some throws when 'modified' to work without a jacket effectively merge together (e.g. many koshi-waza listed above would turn into o-goshi/koshi-guruma), so whether you want to consider them or not is up to you.

There are throws that are basically defined by the grips themselves:

seoi nage (as opposed to ippon seoi nage)
obi otoshi

obi otoshi is often described as "sukui-nage, gripping the belt."


yama arashi
tsurikomi goshi
sode tsurikomi goshi - no sleeves!
tsuri goshi

You can throw hip throws without gi grips, they just will never be called tsurikomi goshi, sode tsurikomi goshi, or tsuri goshi. Hip throws without gi grips from two feet will be classified as ogoshi, uki goshi, or koshi guruma.
Without gi grips, it's more difficult to pull. With gi grips, a viable strategy is to lure an opponent into moving forward without them feeling threatened. This is relatively easy with a loose gi grip, but not really possible with an underhook; once you have an underhook, there is a clear threat and no one is comfortable following. It's also easier to acquire a gi lapel grip than an underhook.
You don't always need to pull if your partner applies forward force. Sumi gaeshi, for example, can function as a counter to single leg shots without requiring grip setup. This complicates trying to answer what throwing techniques won't work without gi grips because there are a lot of normal attacking situations that actually facilitate throwing.
